# Continuity and the closure

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I want to prove that $$f:E\rightarrow F~\text{is continuous}\Rightarrow \overline{f^{-1}(B)}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{B}),\forall B\subset F$$

I say let $B\subset F$ and let $x\in \overline{f^{-1}(B)}$ it means that $$\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\cap f^{-1}(B)\neq \emptyset$$

And i want to prove that $x\in f^{-1}(\overline{B})$ that is $f(x)\in \overline{B}$

that is prove that $\forall W\in \mathcal{V}_{f(x)}, W\cap B\neq \emptyset$

$V\cap f^{-1}(B)\neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \exists y\in V ~\text{and}~ y\in f^{-1}(B)\Rightarrow f(y)\in f(V)~\text{and}~f(y)\in B $ then $f(V)\cap B\neq \emptyset$

But i don't know how to use the fact that $f$ is continuous ?

Thank you.

Comment: But how do you know that for each $W$ you can find an $y$ s.t. $f(y)\in W$ if $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: i don't know how to expres this

Comment: I believe this answers your question. If $W$ is any open neighborhood of $f(x)$, then $f^{-1}(W)=:V$ is open because $f$ is continuous. The rest of your proof is ok then. Or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\overline{B}$ is closed and consequently $f^{-1}\left(\overline{B}\right)$
is closed (since $f$ is continuous).

This with $f^{-1}\left(B\right)\subseteq f^{-1}\left(\overline{B}\right)$
(as a consequence of $B\subseteq\overline{B}$).

Then we are allowed to conclude that $\overline{f^{-1}\left(B\right)}\subseteq f^{-1}\left(\overline{B}\right)$.